# SQLPLUS / AS SYSDBA failed to login ORA-12560

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I am getting

```
ERROR:
ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
```

adapter error when attempt to login as SYSDBA. I did some research and find that firstly in Windows services there weren't any of the `OracleJobSchedulerdb12gr1`; `OracleServicedb12gr1` .. e.t.c.

So I did add them and start:

```
C:\Windows\system32>oradim -new -sid db12gr1
```

So I start a listener as well:

```
C:\Windows\system32>lsnrctl start
```

And after that when I check the status I get:

```
C:\Windows\system32>lsnrctl status

Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1ipc)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "XE" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "XE", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

Not sure if the `UNKNOWN` is the problem I dropped every other `SID_LIST_LISTENER` from `listener.ora` and the `LISTENER` looks like this (in listener.ora) :

```
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )
```

Also I have set my `ORACLE_HOME` to env vars correctly and added to Path the bin folder so I can access `sqlplus`. Defining ORACLE_SID (`set ORACLE_SID=localhost`) does not made any difference before I try to log as sysdba. Also I was able to start the services and start listener only from command prompt opened as administrator of course where still I can't `sqlplus / as sysdba`.

**tnsnames.ora:**

```
EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA = 
  (DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS_LIST = 
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1)) 
    ) 
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
      (SID = CLRExtProc) 
      (PRESENTATION = RO) 
    ) 
  ) 
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
   (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
      (CONNECT_DATA =
        (SERVER = DEDICATED)
        (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
     )
  )
```

I am really out of ideas. Anyone aware what might cost this ?

PS: OS: Windows 10 ; Oracle : 12c

Comment: Have you checked tnsnames.ora as well?

Comment: yep firstly added `tnsnames.ora` to admin folder then `listener.ora`. Of course we are talking for $ORACLE_HOME$/network/admin

Comment: Your SID is XE not localhost, but don"t think that's relevant at this point. Is that your full connection string, or are you including a TNS alias really? Or do you have TWO_TASK or LOCAL set? Is your tnsnames.ora perhaps referring to your PC name rather than localhost; and if it has localhost, does changing it explicitly to 127.0.0.1 instead make any difference?

Comment: We are talking local. Trying to configure oracle on new device and trying to do some install scripts over new created schemes locally in simple words.

Comment: I meant the LOCAL environment variable. The error implies you're connecting over SQL\*Net via a TNS alias, which can be explicit in the connection string or implicit via an environment variable. Do you have a LOCAL variable set, possibly to XE? And please add your `tnsnames.ora` to the question. (I saw a similar questtion recently where localhost apparently wasn't resolving to 127.0.0.1 for some reason, and changing to the IP address seemed to fix it. Not sure if this is the same).

Comment: I added the `tnsnames.ora` but luckily @user3515709 answer solve the problem. About local variable set for XE I really do not think so just that into the `tnsnasmes.ora` file.

Comment: Actually it did solve it until I restarted the computer. Then I needed to start manually some of the oracle12 services in windows services so I can start a listener but this time even with ORACLE_SID=db12gr1 the problem persists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to set your ORACLE_SID environement variable to the right value:
set ORACLE_SID=db12gr1
and make sure your instance service is correctly started.

Comment: Actually this solve the problem util I restarted the computer. No is the same even with the ORACLE_SID set to db12gr1.

Comment: is the service started? what error do you encounter now?

Comment: Actually I had 2 oracles installed and the default one was the other so setting the oracle_sid before logging did the job.

Answer (score 0):

lets do this: 
1. Open Oracle Net Configuration Assistant 
2. Select radio button option at Local Net Service Name Configuration, then click Next 
3. Select radio button option at Reconfigure, then click next 
4. Select net service name you want to reconfigure, either ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA or ORCL, then click Next 
5. input your Service Name, if your service name of installed oracle as ORCL, then write ORCL to the field, then click Next 
6. select the protocol you want to use, for example, select TCP, then click Next 
7. input hostname where your oracle database engine (service) installed, for example, installed on your desktop or notebook, 
   then fill as localhost, and fill your port number (select option Use the Standar port number of 1521) or if use other port, fill the port number 
Then click next. 
8. select Yes perform test,  
  if necessary, change user logon 
then click next 
9. if no configure another net service name, select No and then click next 
10. Click Finish 

you should download, extract and install the ODTwithODAC183.zip and BuildTools_Full.exe if you want use to connect on .net framework from MS Visual Studio